# Bootstrap. Зачем .container нужны медиа-запросы?

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, media-queries

В bootstrap для `.container` есть несколько media-query, так что при некоторых разрешениях экрана `.container` слишком сжимает находящийся в нем контент, искусственно обрезая полезное место. Неужели нельзя было обойтись просто max-`width: 1140px` без дополнительных медиа-запросов? Я верстаю не первый день и для меня логичным выглядит когда контент при любом раскладе максимально прилегает к краям браузера. Однако я понимаю, что в этом есть какой-то смысл и это несет в себе определенные удобства. Вопрос в том, зачем нужны media-queries для `.container`? (я знаю что есть `.container-fluid`, мне важно понять логику ограничений контента. На широком мониторе - понятно что читать широкий текст неудобно, но на более низких разрешениях то зачем?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фиксированная ширина контента дает возможность стабильно показывать задуманный дизайн на абсолютно разных ширинах. Верстку проще\быстрее тестировать. Оправдан пиксельперфект, иначе сверстаешь на какую-то одну ширину по макету, а чуть уже, шире - не всегда будет отвечать задуманному дизайну. Основные размеры экранов широко известны, под них и подогнаны брейкопойнты. Даже на мобильных стараются зафиксировать какую-то одну ширину с помощью мета тегов, чтобы верстка была везде максимально одинаковой. К тому же информация в узких блоках проще воспринимается. Текст например, проще читать с не слишком широкого листа.